# How to get rid of "Switch Application" and "Full Menu" menu on BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry

I have a this screen, that is when loaded, the "Switch Application" and "Full Menu" menu will appear[image]

If I'm not mistaken, the workaround is this:

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time){
    return true;
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. What is the proper solution to get rid of that menu, then?

Comment: I think more info is needed here, but `navigationClick` shouldn't be pushing that menu to the screen, and will intercept your other actions. You say that when loaded the menu appears, so you are likely pushing the menu without realizing it.

Comment: So something on the previous screen is pushing it. Hmm could you give a few examples?

Comment: That would be the best. Usually when making an example with the error, you'll see the error yourself. I wouldn't expect a previous screen to be doing this, but your example you gave to Mister Smith rules out the current screen being the issue.

Comment: I think I made a little progress. so I added the super(NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS) on the previous screen's contructor, and then re-ran the code. Now the Switch Application Menu doesn't show anymore, but the Full Menu still does. Weird, huh?

Comment: That flag doesn't affect when the menu is pushed, just whether to populate with system items. Its possible that when you are pushing the next screen you are also calling `onMenu`, which will show the menu of the previous screen.

Comment: Hmm I don't explicitely call onMenu(). On the other hand, there 4 methods called on that previous screen. 1. onUiEngineAttched (calling a network thread). 2. onSavePrompt (so the save dialog prompt won't appear when the back key is pressed). 3. keyDown (so when the back key is pressed, app will quit). 4. fieldChanged (listener for buttons).

Comment: None of those things should be the cause. Since it's a system menu you're seeing, either `onMenu` or `makeMenu` must be involved. Would you be able to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the screen that is trying to push the new one?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of all menus including that one, override [`onMenu`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#onMenu%28int%29) in your screen and return false. That method is called both with the menu key and the trackball/trackpad:

```
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    ...

    public boolean onMenu(int instance){
        return false;
    }

}
```

(The other option is to swallow the key pulsation using both KeyListener and Trackball listener, but I wont advise that).

If what you want is to keep your own menus but hide the "switch application" one, you should pass the flag [`NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Screen.html#NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS) to the super call in your MainScreen constructor, along with any other flag you might already be passing:

```
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    public MyScreen(){
        super(NO_SYSTEM_MENU_ITEMS);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hello Mr Smith. I tried a simlper screen, as per your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/9SFSHHxs. Well, the menu still appears. I guess something is already happening before the screen is pushed. Hmmm...